# Как сделать форму видимой из слота?

Tags: c++, qt

Хочу в таймере через каждую секунду отображать-скрывать форму. Выдаёт ошибку

```
C:\Users\Radzhab\Documents\test\mainwindow.cpp:37: ошибка: 'class Ui::MainWindow' has no member named 'show'
         ui->show();
             ^
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QTimer>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QTimer::singleShot(1000, this, SLOT(slotHider()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::slotHider()
{
   if (isVisible()){
        ui->hide();
   }
   else
   {
        ui->show();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void MainWindow::slotHider()
{
   if (isVisible()){
        ui->hide();
   }
   else
   {
       ui->show();
   }
}
```

Поменяйте на:

```
void MainWindow::slotHider()
{
   if (isVisible()){
        this->hide();
   }
   else
   {
       this->show();
   }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ) Небольшой вопрос вдогонку. После того как скрыли форму- оно не отображается

Comment: @Radzhab потому что у вас один раз срабатывает таймер )

Comment: спасибо!) пересел с другого яп